# How to search forked repos for repository using GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using GitHub API to search list of repositories forked from specific repository

For example I want to find list of all forked repositories (7,118) for Express.js using this query: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repo:expressjs/express+fork:only

But this shows nothing in result:

```
{
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

Is it possible to build such query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Forks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks) in REST API v3:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/expressjs/express/forks
```

I hope this can help you.